# Documentation from all comments in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, documentation, documentation-generation

How can create a documentation from all classes, methods and attributes comments in Visual Studio 2010 for the C# language?

Comment: What would this document look like?

Comment: Contains all comments related to all solution objects.

Comment: How do you comment an attribute?

Comment: Is there a special reason, why you want your attribute usage to be documented?
As far as writing my documentation led me by now:
The Attribute is described in the comment of the class. In the Documentation you would see, that the class/property/method is tagged with the attribute. So you would have a direct Link.
If you want the reader to get more Information about the Usage, you could use the section "Remarks".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Sandcastle and the Sandcastle Helpfile Builder. It creates CHMs and MSHelpfiles or HTML Pages in MSDN Style. Its simple to use and it can load Soultion Files.
Helpfile Builder with Sandcaste: http://shfb.codeplex.com/
Sandcastle only: http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4):

You can create MSDN like documentation with
[Sandcastle](http://shfb.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 3):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) will generate nice HTML documentation from the comments in your code, provided that you follow a few simple formatting rules.

Answer (score 1):

First it is worth saying that it is commendable that you want to document the API of your libraries so that others (or even **you** at a future date:-) will be able to *use* your code without having to *read* your code. That is a great step in itself!

There are a variety of tools that help automate this task, notably **Doxygen** and **Sandcastle**, as others have previously mentioned. I have not used Doxygen so I will restrict my comments to Sandcastle. Sandcastle, provided by Microsoft, is a great starting point but apparently is quite difficult to use, hence a number of motivated independent developers built more usable interfaces on top of Sandcastle. The premier one of these is **Sandcastle Help File Builder (SHFB)**. With the GUI of SHFB you "simply" create a Sandcastle project, set the project properties to your liking, then build your documentation set as a web site or a CHM file or a couple other formats.

I wrote *simply* in quotes above because working in SHFB is the smallest part of the task in front of you--the much more vast task is decorating your code with appropriate and correct documentation comments (doc-comments) that serve as the "source code" for Sandcastle or other documentation engine. It takes a substantial investment of your time and energy to document all your code but I believe, as you may have inferred, that it is definitely worth it. Besides the aforementioned reason that others will be able to use your code much more easily, I find that documenting my code has one other important benefit--*it helps me write better code*. As I start documenting a new method or class I often remark to myself *"Oh, this parameter would be more clear if it was called Y rather than X."* or *"Oops--this method is not generic enough for others; I need to add a Z parameter."* or *"Hah! This class does not handle these corner cases quite right."* In other words, the act of describing your class or method or parameter makes you think carefully about it and thus **writing doc-comments leads to better code**.

So much for theory; for some practical advice and guideline for Sandcastle and SHFB, take a look at my article on Simple-Talk.com entitled [Taming Sandcastle: A .NET Programmer's Guide to Documenting Your Code](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/taming-sandcastle-a-.net-programmers-guide-to-documenting-your-code/). This article thoroughly documents all the things I found through research and experimentation with SHFB. Accompanying the article is a handy [wallchart](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/code_profiling_made_easy_sandcastlechart.htm?utm_source=simpletalk&utm_medium=email-reflector&utm_content=sandcastlechart&utm_campaign=antsperformanceprofiler) that brings together all the documented and the undocumented elements and attributes that you may use in doc-comments. Here's a fragment of the wallchart to whet your appetite:
[image]